# Can I report tax after April 15 if I am sure I overpay my federal tax and state tax?

Tags: united-states, taxes

Can I report tax after April 15, if I am sure I have overpaid my federal tax (U.S.) and state tax (MD)?

What harm will that cause?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the article [IRS Offers Tips for Taxpayers Who Missed the Tax Deadline](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Newsroom/IRS-Offers-Tips-for-Taxpayers-Who-Missed-the-Tax-Deadline)

> The IRS has some advice for taxpayers who missed the tax 
>   filing deadline.
>
> File as soon as possible.  If you owe federal income tax, 
>   you should file and pay as soon as you can to minimize any penalty and
>   interest charges. There is no penalty for filing a late return if you
>   are due a refund.

Comment: thanks. so it doesn't matter if I don't file an extension?

Comment: On the chance that you miscalculated, and actually have a tiny bit due, I recommend sending in the extension. But the direct answer to you is 'no' if you are certain you have a refund, the form doesn't matter.

Comment: But check the state rules. You could be due a refund from the IRS, but owe the state money.

Comment: +1 (and I have deleted my incorrect answer). But does this mean that if a refund is due year after year, then the taxpayer need never file a tax return as long as the taxpayer is willing to forego the refund? Will the IRS file a _pro forma_ return on behalf of the taxpayer and refund what the IRS thinks is due (along with interest) or will the IRS demand that the taxpayer file a return when it matches up the W-2's and the 1099s and discovers that the return is missing?

Comment: An interesting continuation of the question. I'm speculating, but I imagine that one can fly under the radar for quite some time if they overpay their taxes and never bother. In the strictest sense of the term, they've paid their taxes. At some point, what you suggest may happen, returns with the known W2 info and a note from Uncle Sam.

Comment: the w-2s and 1099s will eventually connected to a person. The IRS will then assume that you would have taken the standard deduction, and calculate your taxes that way. Also keep in mind that after 3 years you can't get back the refunds you were due.